# error when executing a Qt4 application using the WSGI apache module

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, mod-wsgi, wsgi, qgraphicsitem

I'm getting problems with WSGI 3.3 and Qt4 applications. It seems that items of a QGraphicsScene cannot call the childItem() method. The following test script works well when called from the command line, but never finishes when called as WSGI application. I have noticed that this problem is present when using WSGI v3.3 but not with older (2.8) versions.

childItems() method seem to hang and the application becomes unresponsive.

Any clue about what could be happening?

```
from PyQt4.QtGui  import *

import sys
# Show print msgs in apache logs
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

import os
# Allows apache to use DISPLAY. The command "xhost +" could be temporarily required to start Qt applications from the web server
os.environ["DISPLAY"]=":0.0"

QApp = None
def application(environ, start_response):
    global QApp
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    qt_test()

    return [output]

def qt_test():
    QApp = QApplication(["TEST"])
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    obj = QGraphicsRectItem()
    scene.addItem(obj)
    print "EMPTY LIST", obj.childItems()
    obj2 = QGraphicsRectItem()
    obj2.setParentItem(obj)
    print "CHILDREN", obj.childItems()
    print "FINISH"
    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qt_test()
```

environment (working): python 2.6.4, apache 2.2.14, mod-wsgi 2.8, qt 4.6.2, python-qt 4.7.2

environment (problem): python 2.6.6 , 2.2.16, mod-wsgi 3.3, qt 4.6.3, python-qt 4.7.3

Answer (score 1):

People from the mod_wsgi group pointed me to the problem:

> Are you setting:
>
> WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
>
> in Apache configuration.

Comment: Reason most likely being a C extension module that hasn't been code to work with Python sub interpreters. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API